# Regenerating password hash during user authentication with Symfony

Tags: authentication, hash, fosuserbundle, symfony

I'm using Symfony3 and FOSUserBundle and have the below code which enables <kbd>member</kbd> entities (that are from a migrated database) to log in with their usual password by using my class "clubEncoder" instead of Symfony's default bcrypt. "clubEncoder" is working fine (as below) for logging members in. Ideally I want to be able to do the following in the background:

1. Try to authenticate the user using bcrypt
2. If that fails, then try to authenticate again using the "clubEncoder" class
3. If a user is authenticated using "clubEncoder" then the password hash in the database should be re-generated using bcrypt (so step #1 works).

**My questions:**

1. I assume I need to change my `security.yml` to specify both encoders. However, the articles I've read only describe using different encoders for handling different subsets of users - whereas I want to try them both on all users...can this still be done?
2. To regenerate the password hash in the database, I'm assuming the controller needs to be changed however as I'm using FOSUserBundle I do not have the routes to customise. Is this the wrong place to be looking to add the code?

** Below is the code I currently have stable and working for step #2:

### config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\Member
```

### security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\Member:
          id: club.member_encoder

    // AppBundle\Entity\Member:
    //    id: bcrypt
```

### parameters.yml

```
services:
    club.member_encoder:
        class: AppBundle\Service\clubEncoder
```

### clubEncoder.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\PasswordEncoderInterface;

class clubEncoder extends \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\BCryptPasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoderInterface
{
    function __construct($cost=13)
    {
        parent::__construct($cost);
    }


    function isPasswordValid($encoded, $raw,$salt)
    {
        if (parent::isPasswordValid($cost=13, $encoded,$raw,$salt)) return true ;

        else if ($this->comparePasswords($encoded, sha1("3^1nD".$raw."Hx&&%"))) {

            // ADD SOMETHING HERE TO RE-HASH THE PASSWORD TO BCRYPT???????????????????

            return !$this->isPasswordTooLong($raw) &&
                    $this->comparePasswords($encoded, sha1("ThisIsSaltA".$raw."ThisIsSaltB"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding 1): Add another encoder which internally uses `clubEncoder` and the default encoder. 2) I would use the event system to handle this. In case the encoder from 1) encounters the case you describe, dispatch an event. Consume this with an dedicated event listener handling the password update. This way it's not too tightly coupled.

Comment: Thanks Yoshi :) regarding 1) - as I understood it, I thought my clubEncoder `isPasswordValid()` in the question conditionally tests with FOSUserBundle default (bcrypt if I understand correctly) and if that fails then uses my legacy custom one? Regarding 2) - that sounds good. However do you know what event I should be connecting the event listener to? I'm confused as to what to connect to as I have  FOSUserBundle in there as well

Comment: About 1) I actually thought about yet another encoder. One that uses the two existing ones, und just delegates the calls. First to bycrypt, if that fails then to clubEncoder. About 2) In the second case I mentioned before, you would dispatch a custom event (no premade one). Something like `$eventDispatcher->dispatch(AppEvents::LEGACY_PASSWORD_HASH_USED, new YourCustomEvent($user));` (which, of course you have to implement first). For this event you build a [custom listener](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html). But of course this might be a bit over...

Comment: ... complicated, if the transition time issn't really long. Instead of triggering/listening to an event, you could just as well call a service method that rehashes and persists the password. Have this service injected to the extra encoder from 1), and it's still decoupled.

Comment: Hi @Yoshi thanks very much for your help. I've tried doing as you suggested and am still having some issues. If you have time/interest, I've detailed my attempt here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681622/how-to-access-the-user-token-in-an-injected-service-to-reencode-passwords