# How to access the user Token in an injected service to reencode passwords?

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony

I have the below code where I am trying to re-encode passwords as users log in (the database has bee migrated form a legacy website). However, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as I keep getting errors:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "forward" of class "AppBundle\Service\HubAuthenticator".

I have set things up as follows:

## security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\Member:
            id: club.hub_authenticator
```

## services.yml

```
services:
    //This should be central service than then calls the second
    club.hub_authenticator:
        class: AppBundle\Service\HubAuthenticator

    club.password_rehash:
        class: AppBundle\Service\PasswordRehash
```

## Hubauthenticator.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\PasswordEncoderInterface;

class HubAuthenticator extends \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\BCryptPasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoderInterface
{
    function __construct($cost=13)
    {
        parent::__construct($cost);
    }

    function isPasswordValid($encoded, $raw, $salt)
    {
        // Test for legacy authentication (and conditionally rehash the password stored in the database if true)
        if ($this->comparePasswords($encoded, sha1("saltA".$raw."saltB"))) {
            $this->forward('club.password_rehash:rehash');
        }

        // Test for Symfony's Bcrypt authentication (any passwords just rehashed in previous step should work here)
        if (parent::isPasswordValid($cost=13, $encoded,$raw,$salt)) return true ;
    }
}
```

## PasswordRehash.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\PasswordEncoderInterface;

class PasswordRehash extends \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\BCryptPasswordEncoder
{
    // Customises BCryptPasswordEncoder class to use legacy SHA method
    function rehash($member, $raw, $salt)
    {
        //Salt is null as Symfony documentation says it is better to generate a new one
        parent::encodePassword($member->getPlainPassword, $salt=null ) ;
    }
}
```

## Some other previous attempts for completeness:

My *guess* is that the problem is that I am misunderstanding what objects are available to me. My understanding is that the user hasn't been authenticated at this point so have tried and removed the below attempts:

Trying to inject the `$member` into the `HubAuthenticator` service:

```
function __construct($cost=13)
{
    parent::__construct($cost, \Member $member);
}
```

When trying to get the plainpassword to rehash:

```
$this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getPlainPassword();
```

Comment: What do you intend to achieve in your HubAuthenticator class when calling the `forward()` method (which does not exist)? And why does that class extend the `BcryptPasswordEncoder` at all?

Comment: Hi @xabbuh - the `forward()` was wrong - I was just trying out different attempts to get it working(!). The `BcryptPasswordEncoder` I tried removing as you suggested but I'm getting "Error: Cannot access parent:: "....because I have `if (parent::isPasswordValid(...)) return true` in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your services, you can only access what dependencies you've injected.

So, to access the current user object, you need to pass it as argument:

service:

```
club.password_rehash:
    class: AppBundle\Service\PasswordRehash
    arguments: [ "@security.token_storage" ]
```

Constructor:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class HubAuthenticator extends \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\BCryptPasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoderInterface
{
    private $storage;

    function __construct($cost = 13, TokenStorageInterface $storage)
    {
        parent::__construct($cost);

        $this->storage = $storage;
        // Now you can use:
        // $user = $this->storage->getToken()->getUser();
    }
}
```

Then, to access the second service, same way, inject it.

Add it to the service arguments:

```
club.password_rehash:
    class: AppBundle\Service\PasswordRehash
    arguments: [ "@security.token_storage", "@club.password_rehash" ]
```

Add it to your constructor:

```
private $storage;
private $passwordRehash

function __construct($cost = 13, TokenStorageInterface $storage, PasswordRehash $passwordRehash)
{
    parent::__construct($cost);

    $this->storage = $storage;
    $this->passwordRehash = $passwordRehash;
    // Now you can use:
    // $this->passwordRehash->rehash(...);
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks @chalasr - that helped :) It now logs users in with the legacy passwords (without error) but ot is not rehashing. Do you know what could be wrong? `function rehash($raw) { parent::encodePassword($raw, $salt=null);return true; }`

Comment: Is the problem that a password can only be rehashed to the database **after** authentication is completed? ...However the `$raw` plainpassword is only available during authentication?

Comment: @Bendy sorry but I can't help you without know more, maybe you should ask a new question for this specific problem

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @chalasr - I've posted another question with my situation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703134/what-is-preventing-passwords-being-rehashed-with-the-injected-symfony-services