# What is preventing passwords being rehashed with the injected Symfony services (FOSUserBundle)

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony

This is a follow up question to my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681622/how-to-access-the-user-token-in-an-injected-service-to-reencode-passwords) where I am trying to rehash user passwords during authentication to migrate from a legacy database.

After implementing the helpful answer there. I have now hit another problem where I receive no error (with the below code) but the passwords and salt are not being updated in the database:

## security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\Member:
        id: club.hub_authenticator
```

## services.yml

```
services:
    club.hub_authenticator:
        class: AppBundle\Service\HubAuthenticator
        arguments: ["@security.token_storage" ,"@club.password_rehash"]

    club.password_rehash:
        class: AppBundle\Service\PasswordRehash
        arguments: [ "@security.token_storage" ]
```

## HubAuthenticator.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\PasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class HubAuthenticator extends \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\BCryptPasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoderInterface
{
    private $storage ;
    private $passwordRehash ;

    function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $storage, PasswordRehash $passwordRehash, $cost = 13)
    {
        parent::__construct($cost);

        $this->storage=$storage ;
        $this->passwordRehash = $passwordRehash;
    }

    function isPasswordValid($encoded, $raw, $salt)
    {
        // Test for legacy authentication (and conditionally rehash the password in the database)
        if ($this->comparePasswords($encoded, sha1("SaltA".$raw."SaltB"))) {
            $this->passwordRehash->rehash($raw);
            return true ;
        }

        // Test for Bcrypt authentication
        if (parent::isPasswordValid($encoded,$raw,$salt)) return true ;
    }
}
```

## PasswordRehash.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\PasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;


class PasswordRehash extends \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\BCryptPasswordEncoder  implements PasswordEncoderInterface
{
    // private $storage ;

    function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $storage , $cost = 13)
    {
        parent::__construct($cost);
        // $this->storage=$storage ;
    }



    // Customises BCryptPasswordEncoder to use legacy Club SHA method
    function rehash($raw)
    {
        // Commented out as I THINK the $raw is the plainPassword I'm trying to use to reencode the password
        // $user=$this->storage->getToken()->getUser();
        // $token = $this->storage->getToken();

        //Salt left empty as have read this will auto-generate a new one (which is also better practice)
        parent::encodePassword($raw, $salt=null ) ;

        return true ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store the result of `PasswordRehash#rehash()` as the value of your user's password, make your method returning the new password:

```
function rehash($raw)
{        
    return parent::encodePassword($raw, null);
}
```

Then, to update the user, you need to set the new password and store the changes.

Inject the doctrine EntityManager in your service:

```
club.hub_authenticator:
    class: AppBundle\Service\HubAuthenticator
    arguments: ["@security.token_storage" ,"@club.password_rehash", "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" ]
```

And in your class:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $storage, PasswordRehash $passwordRehash, EntityManager $em, $cost = 13)
{
    parent::__construct($cost);

    $this->storage = $storage;
    $this->passwordRehash = $passwordRehash;
    $this->em = $em;
}
```

Then use it:

```
if (!$token = $this->storage->getToken()) {
    return;
}

if ($this->comparePasswords($encoded, sha1("SaltA".$raw."SaltB"))) {
    // Retrieve the user
    $user = $token->getUser();
    // Change the user password
    $user->setPassword($this->passwordRehash->rehash($raw));
    // Save the changes
    $em->flush($user);
}
```

But, I'm really not sure about the logic you are implementing.
I don't see the benefit of extending the BcryptPasswordEncoder.

You should look at [this post](http://qpleple.com/migrate-from-sfguard-to-fosuserbundle/) that shows a quick way to convert the password of your users from a legacy app to FOSUserBundle-compliant passwords in only one time, rather than do it on each authentication.

Then look more at [how to work with services in Symfony2+](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#what-is-a-service).
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks once again :) Firstly: I followed your answer to try and complete what I had started but I'm getting an error "Error: Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object". The error is from `$user = $this->storage->getToken()->getUser();` (I have `private $storage` and have it in `__construct()` as well). Is `->storage->` not right?

Comment: Secondly, thanks for the link to the post of sfGuard. I'll take a look at that too although won't have time until one evening later this week unfortunately

Comment: I added a check to prevent the null token in my example. But, if you can already access the user to update, no need of retrieve it from the storage.

Comment: Great timing - I just booted up to try and figure out what I'm doing wrong :oP I added your updates (thank you) and I don't get the error but now it just doesn't log users in and just reloads the login page with "invalid credentials" - frustrating!

Comment: Hmm... I think that you are updating the password just before authentication (credentials check) so the password is incorrect. If I can give you an advice, don't do this during the authentication. Create an [AuthenticationSuccessListener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html#authentication-success-and-failure-events) and inject the passwordRehash+tokenStorage+entityManager services into (arguments) and do the same logic as actually. Let me know if you need an example. Otherwise, use the link about migrating I given you and update all the passwords at once.

Comment: Thanks @Chalasr - the password hash in the database hasn't been updated after all so I can try the AuthenticationSuccessListener you mentioned - if you're offering to give some example code to your answer though that'd be very much appreciated. Otherwise, once I figure it out I will update for others and accept all the same :)

Comment: I just accepted your answer thank you for your help - I'm still having problems implementing the AuthenticationSuccessListener but having read through, I'm certain that's the correct approach...if you could give guidance on the correct way to do it then that would be great as I can't see anywhere online that uses this combination of migrating passwords encoding with event listeners with FOSUserBundle